# Flux group of surfaces with genus $g\ge2$

Tags: symplectic-topology

I have read in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.5722.pdf) by C. Campos-Apanco and Pedroza (at the end of page 2) that:

> When $(M,\omega)$ is a closed surface of genus greater than one, the flux group is trivial.

Does anyone have a reference for this statement? I have tried looking on the book by Salamon and McDuff (Introduction to Symplectic Topology) as well as searching on the internet, but without success for the moment.

Comment: .....Their paper not only gives the reference [3] of Kedra, *Remarks on the Flux Group*, but says precisely what part of this paper proves triviality (Theorem B). A surface of genus greater than 1 has nonzero Euler characteristic and is aspherical.

Comment: @ChrisGerig Oh, damn, I completely overlooked that paragraph... Thank you very much! If you want you can put your comment into an answer and I will accept it.